# Python 2.7 groupby and then join

Tags: python, join, pandas, group-by

My question is about how to join 2 dataframes, which were created by the `groupby` method and the `sum()` and `max()` functions.

The case is:
I have 1st dataframe with next structure:

[image]

And the second one with the same structure, but instead of `DepartmentDescripton`... variables, I have "Monday", "Tuesday" etc.

Then I try to join them:

```
train_joined_dep_week = pd.merge(tr_bin_dep_grouped, tr_bin_weekday_grouped_flag, left_on=["VisitNumber"], right_on=["VisitNumber"], how='INNER')`
```

the error is

```
KeyError
Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-24-faccedccea7d> in <module>()
----> 1 train_joined_dep_week = pd.merge(tr_bin_dep_grouped, tr_bin_weekday_grouped_flag, left_on=["VisitNumber"], right_on=["VisitNumber"], how='INNER')
[...]
KeyError: 'VisitNumber'
```

Note: I have two different functions for aggregation (`sum()` and `max()`), so I can't just make 1 dataframe. I believe the problem is about wrong data structure after `sum()` func, but I don't understand how to make it in right way.

Answer (score 1):

When you aggregate using `groupby` the columns you're grouping by get moved into the index. You should be able to reset the index with `tr_bin_dep_grouped.reset_index(inplace=True)` and then merge the two dataframes together.